# Scene Builder crushes when import jar file

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder, jfxtras

I try to import jars to the scene builder, I started with `FXRibbon` and it imported to the custom section. then I could not use the components inside(because I did not have some library called `jfxtas`), so I tried to import other jars and get into the mud.

But now the scene builder crashes when I try to import any jar file.

btw when I open the scene builder directly all the custom components are there...

Comment: Without anything like a stack trace this is hard to diagnose

Comment: @tbeernot How can i find the stack trace?
Because there is no errors in inteliJ Event log or terminal.

Comment: This might not apply since you're saying all components are there in the end but a common source of SceneBuilder crashes has been incompatible Java Versions; e. g. if you load a Java 11 JAR into a Java 8 Scene Builder